# org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate entity descriptor: com.mywebapp.model.Product

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I tryed to write Hibernate Tests. But resieve an error: org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate entity descriptor: com.mywebapp.model.Product

Here's a code example. Product.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "product_name", nullable = false)
    private String productName;
    @Column(name = "sale_price")
    private double salePrice;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Order order;

    public Product(String productName, double salePrice) {
        this.productName = productName;
        this.salePrice = salePrice;
    }

    public Product() {
        //Default constructor
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String name) {
        this.productName = name;
    }

    public double getProductSalePrice() {
        return salePrice;
    }

    public void setProductSalePrice(double salePrice) {
        this.salePrice = salePrice;
    }
}
```

HibernateTests look like this:

```
@SpringBootTest//in dem test entity scan scan machen , der findet entity nicht
public class HibernateTests {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
                configure()
                .build();

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
                .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                .buildSessionFactory();
        Session session =sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        Product product = new Product();
        product.setProductName("SomeProduct1");
        product.setProductSalePrice(1290.78);
 

        if (Objects.isNull(session.find(Product.class, product.getId()))) {
            session.persist(product);
        } else {
            session.merge(product);
        }
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
        sessionFactory.close();

    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bitconex</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyWebApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MyWebApp</name>
    <description>MyWebApp</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <start-class>src/main/java/com/bitconex/mywebapp/MyWebAppApplication.java</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
             <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
             <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
             <scope>runtime</scope>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
             <scope>test</scope>
             <exclusions>
                 <exclusion>
                     <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                     <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
             </exclusions>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
             <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
             <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
             <version>5.3.0</version>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
         <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
             <artifactId>webjars-locator-core</artifactId>
         </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

     </dependencies>

     <build>
         <plugins>
             <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                 <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
             </plugin>

         </plugins>
     </build>

 </project>
```

application.properties look like this:

```
#H2 Database Configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/CatalogProDB
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password

#Hibernate Configuration for PostgreSQL
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true

server.port=8081
```

I also tried using persistence.xml but it didn't work out.

Comment: In entity class from where are annotations imported, `javax` or `jakarta` ?

Comment: it is imported jakarta

Comment: can you also share the package structure of the project ? or better to post project to github and give here the link, i`m going to check.

Comment: https://github.com/IrinaWorkAccount/Order_Management_Java.git This one. Feature brunch.

Comment: in this case, remove `hibernate.cfg.xml`, `persistence.xml` `hibernate.cfg.xml` and retry, after it i was able to run the test that you have, an I dont see any exception like `UnknownEntityTypeException`

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand.Without this class, I receive this: Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]
 at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:53)
 at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:244)
 at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:233)
at com.bitconex.mywebapp.HibernateTests.main(HibernateTests.java:18)